# import query which is generated in excel into teradata

Tags: sql, excel, teradata, vba

I have generated a query in the excel by using macros now "**i want to import these queries into teradata and compile it and display the result Automatically**".Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

With sufficient privileges in the database you can create a macro or macros that encapsulate the query. The macro(s) can be built to accept parameters if necessary. Once you have the macros built on Teradata you can replace the SQL in your Excel Macros with:

`EXEC {Database}.{Macro}({parm1}, {parm2}, ... {parmn});`

[Excel VBA - Query on a Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285857/excel-vba-query-on-a-spreadsheet) - Take a look at  the answers on this SO question. You may find something to help you in the right direction with your VBA coding. It will need to be tweaked to connect with your Teradata environment.

Comment: actually the data in excel sheet is like "select * from stu(table name);" from A1 to A6355 i want to run this data of excel in the teradata but if i import this it is imported as a table data not as query.plz help me to over come this.

Comment: but all this must happen automatically like macros.plz anyone help me with this.I am new to teradata and excel macros.help me to do step by step.

Comment: So you have 6000 SELECT statements stored in your Excel spreadsheet that you wish to execute against Teradata via an Excel macro, correct?

Comment: i have n number of datas (in format of queries) only in column "A" of third sheet(it will change according to the data in sheet1) that i want to execute against Teradata via an Excel macro.plz help me with this...............

Comment: plz anyone help me with this problem,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Have you searched SO to find examples of using VBA macros to connect to a database via ADO and iterate through a collection of cells on a given worksheet? There are several examples that you may be able combine to build your solution.

Comment: Added link to an SO example to help get you going in the right direction.

Comment: "so" means i am new to IT can u plz explain me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

store your queries into single string variable  and remember to put ";" between queries. then use this guide 
http://voices.yahoo.com/teradata-ms-excel-vba-2687156.html?cat=59