# Load csv file into a VBA array rather than Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently able to enter csv file data into Excel VBA by uploading the data via the code below then handling the table, surely not the best way as I am only interested in some of the data and delete the sheet after using the data:

```
Sub CSV_Import() 
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String 

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'set to current worksheet name 

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", ,"Please select text file...") 

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1")) 
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited 
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True 
     .Refresh 
End With 
End Sub
```

Is it possible to simply load the csv into a two dimensional variant array in VBA rather than going through the use of an excel worksheet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, after looking into this, the solution I have arived at is to use ADODB (requires reference to ActiveX Data Objects, this loads the csv file into array without cycling the rows columns. Does require the data to be in good condition.

```
Sub LoadCSVtoArray()

strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"
cn.Open strcon
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SAMPLE.csv;"

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rsARR() As Variant

Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)
rsARR = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
rs.Close
Set cn = Nothing

[a1].Resize(UBound(rsARR), UBound(Application.Transpose(rsARR))) = rsARR

End Sub
```

Comment: Huge if true. Let me try it!

Comment: It truncates datatypes. If for example the first x rows of a column are 1 - as integer, and x+1 rows are 1.134 etc float), it will convert it to integer automatically. 

Possible solutions to that could be to use a schema.ini file - which I find a mess

Another one is to change the registry and allow adodb to look at more rows to determine the datatype. Not good thing in a work pc, where there are no admin rights.

Comment: Yikes. ADODB to read a csv file is an overkill. Specially if you realize a csv file is just a text file and can be handled better using a TextStream.

Comment: @LayGonzález Not really. Look at the solution I provided below. ADODB is an overkill.

Comment: ADODB isn't overkill when you have a large CSV file! And, unlike my dazzlingly clever solution above, ADODB handles commas in properly-encapsulated text strings. A suggested improvement for really big file: load it into arrays of a thousand rows using the rowcount parameter: `rs.GetRows(1024)` until rs reports `rs.EOF=TRUE`  ...Also, you may need to strip out the Byte Order Marker. The grisly details are in this Stack reply:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317605/escaping-non-ascii-characters-or-how-to-remove-the-bom/41046895#41046895

Answer (score 27):

Okay, looks like you need two things: stream the data from the file, and populate a 2-D array.

I have a 'Join2d' and a 'Split2d' function lying around (I recall posting them in another reply on StackOverflow a while ago). Do look at the comments in the code, there are things you might need to know about efficient string-handling if you're handling large files.

However, it's not a complicated function to use: just paste the code if you're in a hurry.

Streaming the file is simple BUT we're making assumptions about the file format: are the lines in the file delimited by Carriage-Return characters or the Carriage-Return-and-Linefeed character pair? I'm assuming 'CR' rather than CRLF, but you need to check that.

Another assumption about the format is that numeric data will appear as-is, and string or character data will be encapsulated in quote marks. This *should* be true, but often isn't... And stripping out the quote marks adds a lot of processing - lots of allocating and deallocating strings - which you really don't want to be doing in a large array. I've short-cut the obvious cell-by-cell find-and-replace, but it's still an issue on large files.

**If your file has commas embedded in the string values, this code won't work**: and don't try to code up a parser that picks out the encapsulated text and skips these embedded commas when splitting-up the rows of data into individual fields, because this intensive string-handling can't be optimised into a fast and reliable csv reader by VBA.

Anyway: here's the source code: watch out for line-breaks inserted by StackOverflow's textbox control:

**Running the code:**

Note that you'll need a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (system32\scrrun32.dll)

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim arrX As Variant
    arrX = ArrayFromCSVfile("MyFile.csv")
End Sub
```

**Streaming a csv file.**

Note that I'm assuming your file is in the temp folder:
 C:\Documents and Settings[$USERNAME]\Local Settings\Temp
You'll need to use filesystem commands to copy the file into a local folder: it's always quicker than working across the network.

```
Public Function ArrayFromCSVfile( _
    strName As String, _
    Optional RowDelimiter As String = vbCr, _
    Optional FieldDelimiter = ",", _
    Optional RemoveQuotes As Boolean = True _
) As Variant

    ' Load a file created by FileToArray into a 2-dimensional array
    ' The file name is specified by strName, and it is exected to exist
    ' in the user's temporary folder. This is a deliberate restriction:
    ' it's always faster to copy remote files to a local drive than to
    ' edit them across the network

    ' RemoveQuotes=TRUE strips out the double-quote marks (Char 34) that
    ' encapsulate strings in most csv files.

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strTemp As String

    Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    strTemp = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(Scripting.TemporaryFolder).ShortPath
    strFile = objFSO.BuildPath(strTemp, strName)
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then  ' raise an error?
        Exit Function
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = "Reading the file... (" & strName & ")"

    If Not RemoveQuotes Then
        arrData = Join2d(objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading).ReadAll, RowDelimiter, FieldDelimiter)
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading the file... Done"
    Else
        ' we have to do some allocation here...

        strTemp = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading).ReadAll
        Application.StatusBar = "Reading the file... Done"

        Application.StatusBar = "Parsing the file..."

        strTemp = Replace$(strTemp, Chr(34) & RowDelimiter, RowDelimiter)
        strTemp = Replace$(strTemp, RowDelimiter & Chr(34), RowDelimiter)
        strTemp = Replace$(strTemp, Chr(34) & FieldDelimiter, FieldDelimiter)
        strTemp = Replace$(strTemp, FieldDelimiter & Chr(34), FieldDelimiter)

        If Right$(strTemp, Len(strTemp)) = Chr(34) Then
            strTemp = Left$(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
        End If

        If Left$(strTemp, 1) = Chr(34) Then
            strTemp = Right$(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
        End If

        Application.StatusBar = "Parsing the file... Done"
        arrData = Split2d(strTemp, RowDelimiter, FieldDelimiter)
        strTemp = ""
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Set objFSO = Nothing
    ArrayFromCSVfile = arrData
    Erase arrData
End Function
```

**Split2d**
Creates a 2-dimensional VBA array from a string:

```
Public Function Split2d(ByRef strInput As String, _
    Optional RowDelimiter As String = vbCr, _
    Optional FieldDelimiter = vbTab, _
    Optional CoerceLowerBound As Long = 0 _
    ) As Variant

    ' Split up a string into a 2-dimensional array.

    ' Works like VBA.Strings.Split, for a 2-dimensional array.
    ' Check your lower bounds on return: never assume that any array in
    ' VBA is zero-based, even if you've set Option Base 0
    ' If in doubt, coerce the lower bounds to 0 or 1 by setting
    ' CoerceLowerBound
    ' Note that the default delimiters are those inserted into the
    '  string returned by ADODB.Recordset.GetString

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Coding note: we're not doing any string-handling in VBA.Strings -
    ' allocating, deallocating and (especially!) concatenating are SLOW.
    ' We're using the VBA Join & Split functions ONLY. The VBA Join,
    ' Split, & Replace functions are linked directly to fast (by VBA
    ' standards) functions in the native Windows code. Feel free to
    ' optimise further by declaring and using the Kernel string functions
    ' if you want to.

    ' ** THIS CODE IS IN THE PUBLIC DOMAIN **
    '    Nigel Heffernan   Excellerando.Blogspot.com

    Dim i   As Long
    Dim j   As Long

    Dim i_n As Long
    Dim j_n As Long

    Dim i_lBound As Long
    Dim i_uBound As Long
    Dim j_lBound As Long
    Dim j_uBound As Long

    Dim arrTemp1 As Variant
    Dim arrTemp2 As Variant

    arrTemp1 = Split(strInput, RowDelimiter)

    i_lBound = LBound(arrTemp1)
    i_uBound = UBound(arrTemp1)

    If VBA.LenB(arrTemp1(i_uBound)) <= 0 Then
        ' clip out empty last row: a common artifact in data
         'loaded from files with a terminating row delimiter
        i_uBound = i_uBound - 1
    End If

    i = i_lBound
    arrTemp2 = Split(arrTemp1(i), FieldDelimiter)

    j_lBound = LBound(arrTemp2)
    j_uBound = UBound(arrTemp2)

    If VBA.LenB(arrTemp2(j_uBound)) <= 0 Then
     ' ! potential error: first row with an empty last field...
        j_uBound = j_uBound - 1
    End If

    i_n = CoerceLowerBound - i_lBound
    j_n = CoerceLowerBound - j_lBound

    ReDim arrData(i_lBound + i_n To i_uBound + i_n, j_lBound + j_n To j_uBound + j_n)

    ' As we've got the first row already... populate it
    ' here, and start the main loop from lbound+1

    For j = j_lBound To j_uBound
        arrData(i_lBound + i_n, j + j_n) = arrTemp2(j)
    Next j

    For i = i_lBound + 1 To i_uBound Step 1

        arrTemp2 = Split(arrTemp1(i), FieldDelimiter)

        For j = j_lBound To j_uBound Step 1
            arrData(i + i_n, j + j_n) = arrTemp2(j)
        Next j

        Erase arrTemp2

    Next i

    Erase arrTemp1

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Split2d = arrData

End Function
```

**Join2D** 
Turns a 2-dimensional VBA array to a string:

```
Public Function Join2d(ByRef InputArray As Variant, _
    Optional RowDelimiter As String = vbCr, _
    Optional FieldDelimiter = vbTab, _
    Optional SkipBlankRows As Boolean = False _
    ) As String

    ' Join up a 2-dimensional array into a string. Works like the standard
    '  VBA.Strings.Join, for a 2-dimensional array.
    ' Note that the default delimiters are those inserted into the string
    '  returned by ADODB.Recordset.GetString

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Coding note: we're not doing any string-handling in VBA.Strings -
    ' allocating, deallocating and (especially!) concatenating are SLOW.
    ' We're using the VBA Join & Split functions ONLY. The VBA Join,
    ' Split, & Replace functions are linked directly to fast (by VBA
    ' standards) functions in the native Windows code. Feel free to
    ' optimise further by declaring and using the Kernel string functions
    ' if you want to.

    ' ** THIS CODE IS IN THE PUBLIC DOMAIN **
    '   Nigel Heffernan   Excellerando.Blogspot.com

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim i_lBound As Long
    Dim i_uBound As Long
    Dim j_lBound As Long
    Dim j_uBound As Long

    Dim arrTemp1() As String
    Dim arrTemp2() As String

    Dim strBlankRow As String

    i_lBound = LBound(InputArray, 1)
    i_uBound = UBound(InputArray, 1)

    j_lBound = LBound(InputArray, 2)
    j_uBound = UBound(InputArray, 2)

    ReDim arrTemp1(i_lBound To i_uBound)
    ReDim arrTemp2(j_lBound To j_uBound)

    For i = i_lBound To i_uBound

        For j = j_lBound To j_uBound
            arrTemp2(j) = InputArray(i, j)
        Next j

        arrTemp1(i) = Join(arrTemp2, FieldDelimiter)

    Next i

    If SkipBlankRows Then

        If Len(FieldDelimiter) = 1 Then
            strBlankRow = String(j_uBound - j_lBound, FieldDelimiter)
        Else
            For j = j_lBound To j_uBound
                strBlankRow = strBlankRow & FieldDelimiter
            Next j
        End If

        Join2d = Replace(Join(arrTemp1, RowDelimiter), strBlankRow, RowDelimiter, "")
        i = Len(strBlankRow & RowDelimiter)

        If Left(Join2d, i) = strBlankRow & RowDelimiter Then
            Mid$(Join2d, 1, i) = ""
        End If

    Else

        Join2d = Join(arrTemp1, RowDelimiter)

    End If

    Erase arrTemp1

End Function
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Loving your code and hating your formatting! Suggest you check out SO's formatting tricks to kill the excess spacing

Comment: Will not work if fields contain linebreaks or field delimiter.

Comment: Torben is correct: 'Will not work if fields contain linebreaks or field delimiter' - if you pass my code a string containing the delimiting characters of a csv file, it fails. Your next question: how did those characters get into a csv file in the first place? In the cases where the csv file is correctly formatted, with strings encapsulated in quotes, 'forbidden' characters can be encoded... So you've got to do 'replace' on the incoming data, one string at a time.

Comment: For `ArrayFromCSVfile`, shouldn't `arrData = Join2d(strTemp, RowDelimiter, FieldDelimiter)` actually be `arrData = Split2d(strTemp, RowDelimiter, FieldDelimiter)`, ie `Split2d` instead of `Join2d`?

Comment: Thanks [@dashnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3661120/dashnick) - fixed, and please accept my apologies for not spotting this before I posted the code.

Comment: There is a second point in the code of `ArrayFromCSVfile` at which `Join2d` appears when `Split2d` ought to appear instead - in the line after `If Not RemoveQuotes Then`.

Comment: The statement "...because this intensive string-handling can't be optimised into a fast and reliable csv reader by VBA", turns out to be mistaken. Fast (by VBA standards) and reliable VBA parsers for RFC4180-compliant csv files (which may include embedded delimiters, line feeds etc.) are available on GitHub. One example (I'm the author) is at https://github.com/PGS62/VBA-CSV and the README links to others.

Comment: Interesting point from Phil Swannell - I will look at that GitHub when I get home. Note, however, that the vast majority of Excel users and developers, who will be working in a corporate environment, will be prevented by the company security policy from viewing material on an external GitHub.

Answer (score 13):

Yes read it as a text file.

See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

    Open "C:\MyFile.CSV" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Like I mentioned below in the comments, AFAIK, there is no direct way of filling a 2d Array from a csv. You will have to use the code that I gave above and then split it per line and finally filling up a 2D array which can be cumbersome. Filling up a column is easy but if you specifically want say from Row 5 to Col 7 Data then it becomes cumbersome as you will have to check if there are sufficient columns/rows in the data. Here is a basic example to get Col B in a 2D Array.

**NOTE**: I have not done any error handling. I am sure you can take care of that.

Let's say our CSV File looks likes this.

[image]

When you run this code

```
Option Explicit

Const Delim As String = ","

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String, TmpAr() As String
    Dim TwoDArray() As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Open "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Sample.CSV" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    n = 0

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        If Len(Trim(strData(i))) <> 0 Then
            TmpAr = Split(strData(i), Delim)
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve TwoDArray(1, 1 To n)
            '~~> TmpAr(1) : 1 for Col B, 0 would be A
            TwoDArray(1, n) = TmpAr(1)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To n
        Debug.Print TwoDArray(1, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

You will get the output as shown below

[image]

BTW, I am curious that since you are doing this in Excel, why not use inbuilt `Workbooks.Open` or `QueryTables` method and then read the range into a 2D array? That would be much simpler...

Comment: And this will return a two dimensional array which I can handle as if it is in the same format as when it is a table in excel worksheet?

Comment: No. This will give you a Single Dimentional Array. Where each row will be stored in the array separately. You can further split each row of the array using "," as a delim which will again give you an array.

Comment: so handle each line with split per line? This may take longer than the original method. Is there a way to load directly into a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: Any chance of posting code required to get the file from csv file into the two dimension array, then I can test to see how it performs, thanks.

Comment: You mean "handle each line with split per line"?

Comment: I would like to avoid using the QueryTable method of extracting the data into a worksheet, which is essentialy a two dimensional array. So would like code to load a two dimensional array with the csv data. I am OK using arrays of data, but not sure of how to fill it from the csv file.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, AFAIK, there is no direct way of filling a 2d Array from a csv. You will have to use the code that I gave above and then split it per line and finally filling up a 2D array which can be cumbersome...

Comment: It is this 'Cumbersome' part I would like to test. The splitting of the lines will require redim array and such? It is this bit of code added to the fist bit which I am looking for. Once I have a start point I can test it, and maybe it will be acceptable.

Comment: Yup, you will have to redim it. I can show you an example on how to get data from say Col B in CSV to a 2D array?

Comment: For my data I have 3 columns: A=Currency (USD or EUR), B=ValidFromDate(yyyymmdd), C=ExchangeRate(as 5.decimal double). So an example to get 3 columns and many rows would be most helpfull.

Comment: I already have my answer ready based on my lst comment. I was just proof reading it. Hope that it helps? I am sure you can amend it to suit your needs?

Comment: Thank you very much, unless there is a way to poulate the 2D array directly from the csv file, this will do what I require as I can handle each line before it hist the array, which may help me in the long run. The "simpler" QueryTable method is the one I have in place, But I am always looking for ways to improve my code, and getting rid of a worksheet object and handling thereof seems like a good candidate for improvement. Thanks again for your time on this one.

Comment: See next reply: there's a fairly rapid way of populating a 2d array from a text stream containing field delimiters and row delimiters... And a csv file is exactly that

Answer (score 2):

To get a known format csv data file into a 2D array I finally adopted the following method, which seems to work well and is quite quick.
I decided that file read operations are fairly fast nowadays, so I run a first pass on the csv file to get the size required for both dimension of the array. With the array suitably dimensioned it is then a simple task to re-read the file, line by line, and populate the array.

```
Function ImportTestData(ByRef srcFile As String, _
                        ByRef dataArr As Variant) _
                        As Boolean

Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, Fo As TextStream
Dim line As String, Arr As Variant
Dim lc As Long, cc As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

ImportTestData = False
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set Fo = FSO.OpenTextFile(srcFile)

' First pass; read the file to get array size
lc = 0 ' Counter for number of lines in the file
cc = 0 ' Counter for number of columns in the file
While Not Fo.AtEndOfStream  ' Read the csv file line by line
    line = Fo.ReadLine
    If lc = 0 Then ' Count commas to get array's 2nd dim index
        cc = 1 + Len(line) - Len(Replace(line, ",", ""))
    End If
    lc = lc + 1
Wend
Fo.Close

' Set array dimensions to accept file contents
ReDim dataArr(0 To lc - 1, 0 To cc - 1)
'Debug.Print "CSV has "; n; " rows with "; lc; " fields/row"
If lc > 1 And cc > 1 Then
    ImportTestData = True
End If

' Second pass; Re-open data file and copy to array
Set Fo = FSO.OpenTextFile(srcFile)
lc = 0
While Not Fo.AtEndOfStream
    line = Fo.ReadLine
    Arr = Split(line, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        dataArr(lc, i) = Arr(i)
    Next i
    lc = lc + 1
Wend

End Function   'ImportTestData()
```

I created this as a Function rather than a Sub to get a simple return value, if required. 
Reading a file with 8,500 rows of 20 columns takes approximately 180ms.
This method assumes that the structure (number of delimiters) of the CSV file is the same for every row, typical of a data logging application.

Comment: You don't need to know the dimension of the array in advance if you use the Redim statement. Also there is Split function that handles the parsing of the csv file. Need to read the VBA documentation.

Comment: @agcala. Actually you do need to know the dimensions  (well, one of them at least) as `ReDim Preserve` only allows you to change the last dimension

Comment: @nigelH you are making a couple of assumptions here which may or may not be justified: 1) that the first line in the CSV is representative of all lines, and 2) that there are no quoted value with embedded `,`'s in the data.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes I have made the assumption that all lines will be the same, typically from a data logger, where there will also be no embedded delimiters. Without knowing the length of file in advance ReDim Preserve would have to be used every time round the loop, so doing a first pass to find the dimensions required avoids that overhead.

Comment: @nigelh regarding the length of the array thing, I was actually defending your approach.  Regarding the assumptions,  if they are justified then fine.  However there is nothing in the OP to suggest they are justified in this case.  Furthermore,  to create a generalised CSV handler these assumptions cannot be made.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Your comments are much appreciated and I have edited the text to indicate this applies to known format of csv file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a code like this

```
Dim line As String, Arr
Dim FSO As Object, Fo As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fo = FSO.OpenTextFile("csvfile.csv")
While Not Fo.AtEndOfStream
 line = Fo.ReadLine      ' Read the csv file line by line
 Arr = Split(line, ",")  ' The csv line is loaded into the Arr as an array
 For i = 0 To UBound(Arr) - 1: Debug.Print Arr(i) & " ";: Next
 Debug.Print
Wend

 01/01/2019 1 1 1 36 55.6 0.8 85.3 95 95 109 102 97 6 2.5 2.5 3.9 
 01/01/2019 1 2 0 24 0.0 2.5 72.1 89 0 0 97 95 10 6.7 4.9 3.9 
 01/01/2019 1 3 1 36 26.3 4 80.6 92 92 101 97 97 8 5.5 5.3 3.7 
 01/01/2019 1 4 0 16 30.0 8 79.2 75 74 87 87 86 10 3.8 4 4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

### The following solution does not use ActiveX:

I wrote code to import a csv (actually tab-separated) file into an array. That code is the following.

First let's designate the array (initially it is completely void but it will be resized appropriately later):

```
Dim TxtFile$()
```

Now for the sub-procedure:

```
' Fills TxtFile$() array
Sub FillTextFileArray(A$)

'***********************************************************************
' Declarations
'***********************************************************************
Dim I, J As Integer
Dim LineString As String
'***********************************************************************

I = -1: J = 0    ' Will hold array dimentions

Open A$ For Input As #1

Do While Not EOF(1)    ' Loop until end of file.
    Line Input #1, LineString
    LineString = LineString + vbTab    ' If not done empty lines give error with Split()
    I = I + 1
    If J < UBound(Split(LineString, vbTab)) Then J = UBound(Split(LineString, vbTab))
Loop

ReDim TxtFile$(1 To I + 4, 1 To J + 4)    ' Not indexed from 0 ! (Plus some room at the end.) This is done to match worksheet format.
Seek #1, 1    ' Reset to start

I = -1    ' Will hold array row index
Do While Not EOF(1)    ' Loop until end of file.
    Line Input #1, LineString
    LineString = LineString + vbTab    ' If not done empty lines give error with Split()
    I = I + 1
    For J = 0 To UBound(Split(LineString, vbTab))
        TxtFile$(I + 1, J + 1) = Split(LineString, vbTab)(J)
    Next J
Loop

Close #1    ' Close file.

' TxtFile$() now holds the contents of the text file

End Sub
```

Obviously you can then do what you want with the TxtFile$ array. A$ is the location and name of the text file. As already said, this particular code works with tab-delimited files (vbTab), not comma-delimited (separated), but any adaptation should not be too difficult. It has the advantage of avoiding ActiveX complications.

Answer (score 0):

These days, GitHub hosts at least three CSV parsers that do exactly what the OP asked for - load a CSV file into a VBA array.

I'm the author of this one:
https://github.com/PGS62/VBA-CSV

It handles a broad variety of CSV files, including those with "embedded" commas, line-feeds etc, and those with a varying number of fields per row. I provide links to alternative VBA CSV parsers in the README file.