# Excel VBA code to search a row of cells for multiple phrases and output "1" if any of them are found

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that will allow me to search for multiple phrases like "energy" and "fuel" within multiple cells in a row like C1:F1 and output a 1 to a specific cell like J1 if any of the phrases are found in any cells. These cells may contain multiple words like "directed energy" and I would still like it to output a 1 if it finds the phrase energy anywhere in the cell. I would also like it to be non case-sensitive if possible!! Thank you so much for the help I really truly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you written anything so far? And where are the phrases, in a cell range somewhere in your spreadsheet?

Comment: I've only written a formula that works on one cell, and yes the phrases are in cells on a spreadsheet between C1 and F1.

Comment: This is the formula I have so far =if((iserr(search("energy", c1,1))),0,1)

Comment: And you want this in VBA and not formulas?

Comment: Also, the SEARCH function in Excel will work regardless of capitalization.

Comment: Either VBA or a formula, everything I've tried so far hasn't worked

Comment: The function I've written only works on one cell and I want to make it work on a range of cells, specifically one row

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.  I want to give @TedWilliams credit for the double "transpose" line, the idea was taken from his excellent post - [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet).

```
Sub checkString()
    Dim s As String, r As Range, vArr, v
    Dim b As Boolean
    Dim w As Worksheet

    vArr = Array("energy", "fuel") 'items to search for, change to suit

    Set w = ActiveSheet
    Set r = w.Range("C1:F1").Rows(1)

    With Application
        s = Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(r.Value)))
    End With

    For Each v In vArr
        b = (InStr(1, s, CStr(v), vbTextCompare) > 0)
        If b Then Exit For
    Next v

    w.Range("J1").Value = -b
End Sub
```