# Compare two ranges of cells and return a value based on comparison

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone point me at a function or code that can compare a range of cells to a range of cells in another sheet and return a value. The lists have the same format:

**Example:**

Compare `Sheet1 A1 B1 C1 D1` to `Sheet 2  A1 B1 C1 D1` and return `Sheet 2 E1` value

In my head it's like a multiple column `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: @TimWilliams suggested a beautiful method sometime ago. Please do a search in SO. If I find that link, then I will post it here.

Comment: Found it :) See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet/19396257#19396257)

Comment: do you mean return the answer to the comparison (equal, not equal) in sheet2 E1? or just return whatever is in sheet2 E1 regardless? what are you hoping to achieve with the comparison? are you looking to see if they match exactly? are you looking to find which columns dont match, or which ones gave the greater value?

Comment: on sheet 2 - E1 has a job role name. If the four fields from sheet 1 match the very same values in sheet 2 then Sheet 2 E 1 is returned to Sheet 1 - this sounds like matching  binary in my head

Comment: OP, would you kindly edit your question and include your data there? It is not the practice here to put your data in the comments section. Kindly put ***everything*** that's the issue with your question in your post above. This way, we don't refer to comments while helping you out answer your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can move the job code to E2 then this, adapted from the link siddharth posted will work:

```
 Dim a As Application
 Set a = Application

    If Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(Sheets(1).Rows(1).Value)), chr(0)) = _
   Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(Sheets(2).Rows(1).Value)), chr(0)) Then


MsgBox (Sheets(2).Cells(2, "E"))
End If
```

Change the rows as necessary, and instead of msgbox, save it as a variable or however you want.

### Edit

the following will work also:

```
Dim a As Application
Set a = Application
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range

Set rngA = Range("A1", "D1")
Set rngB = Range("A2", "D2")


If Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rngA.Value)), chr(0)) = _
   Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rngB.Value)), chr(0)) Then


    MsgBox (Sheets(2).Cells(2, "E"))
End If
```

provided that the ranges to compare are only 1 row each. if either range spans more than one row it wont work.

### Edit2

```
Sub getValuesOnRow()
  Dim sourceRange As Range
  Dim targetRange As Range

  Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1))
  Set targetRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 1)

  sourceRange.Copy
  targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False,     Transpose:=True

End Sub

Sub Compare()
Dim a As Application
Set a = Application
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range


Set rngA = Sheets(1).Range("A1", "A6")
Set rngB = Sheets(2).Range("A1", "A6")


If Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(Sheets(1).Rows(7).Value)), chr(0)) = _
   Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(Sheets(2).Rows(7).Value)), chr(0)) Then


    Sheets(1).Cells(6, "A").Value = Sheets(2).Cells(6, "A")
End If



End Sub
```

So that there is 2 methods. the first, takes a particular column, in the example, column 1, and the first 5 cells, and puts it on 1 row. in the example, row 7. Then the transpose method, takes the row and compares it. so the first method can be used to get a particular column on a row, and the second can be used to compare 2 rows and return a particular cell if the comparison is true.

Comment: thanks but that actually wont work for me as I have multiple rows that   have different job IDs - so I cant move to E2 I have about 30 jobs on sheet 2 that are identified by '1' or Null in 5 cells - so i need to compare Sheet1:A1:A5 to Sheet2:A1:A5 and if all cells matche  it then returns the value Sheet2:A6 to Sheet1:A6 - if that doesnt match then  compare Sheet1:A1:A5 to Sheet2:B1:B5 and so on. hope this has described it better....cheers all

Comment: hmm.. i just editted, let me check to see if it works for columns... it should.

Comment: Damn.. it does not.. kay hang on.

Comment: How much do you know of VBA? if I give you code, are you able to adapt it to your particular situation?

Comment: Ok, so the 2 methods will do exactly what is needed in conjunction with eachother. You'll need to either loop it or manually edit and run them for each column, your pick.

Comment: Awesome the first version works great !!!!!! I just need to add the loop :) though will try this myself and learn THANKS ALL

Comment: @user3257536: Kindly mark this answer as accepted if you found it helpful. This is how we say thanks in SO. :)

Comment: Thanks BK but I doubt they saw that or will be back unless they runs into more problems. least they did say thank you though :)

Comment: found it! was toooooo obvious!