# Find the next visible row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function to return the next visible row in an autofiltered list.

In a sheet with an autofiltered range the code below returns a #VALUE error:

```
Function FindNextVisible(S As Range) As Range
Dim L As Range
Dim R As Range
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
Set L = Range(S, S.End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each R In L
    counter = counter + 1
    If counter = 2 Then FindNextVisible = R
Next 
End Function
```

I suspect a beginners error...

**UPDATE 1:**
Ok great advice. I can't use SpecialCells. Unfortunately the VBA is not strong in me and I'm having trouble with a Sub version.

Perhaps there is another way. I want to compare text between non-contiguous (due to filtering) rows, but I don't know how to provide the formula with a reference to the next visible row.

Comment: You can not use SpecialCells inside a function, and get expected results.

Comment: Specifically a Function called from a worksheet formula: OK if calling it from another Sub for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams: You can use `SpecialCells` inside a UDF.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - my bad.  I thought I remembered some issue with SpecialCells

Comment: @TimWilliams: Yes there are issues with specialcells. I was only pointing to the fact that using them will not give you an error especially `#Value` error. It will just give you unexpected results. The reason why OP was getting `#Value` error is because he was assigning values to a range object without using `SET` and not becuase of `SpecialCells`

Comment: Too much of confusion. I deleted my post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tthe following should accomplish what you are looking for.

```
Public Function NextVisibleCell(Range As Range) As Range
Application.Volatile
Dim i As Long
Set Range = Range.Cells(Range.Rows.Count, Range.Columns.Count)
For i = 1 To Rows.Count - Range.Row
    If Not Range.Offset(i).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        Set NextVisibleCell = Range.Offset(i)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: + 1 This does get the value of the next visible row.

Comment: This is a very imp point that OP wants to handle `want to compare text between non-contiguous (due to filtering) rows, but I don't know how to provide the formula with a reference to the next visible row.`

Comment: You *can* return a reference to a range from a UDF... `Function Nxt(r As Range) As Range: Set Nxt = r.Offset(1, 0): End Function` If you feed the return value from this into (eg) `OFFSET()` it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams: True and then OP can use your [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet/19396257#19396257) code to compare the rows?

Comment: @TimWilliams You are correct not sure why I thought you couldn't, Updated Answer to reflect.