# Type mismatch error, why?

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

Can anyone explain why there is type mismatch when **If range...** runs?
here is my code

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
For i = 2 To 1000
For x = 3 To 999
If Range("k" & i & ":bn" & i).Value = Range("k" & x & ":bn" & x).Value And Cells(i, 5).Value <> Cells(x, 5).Value Then
Range("k" & i & ":bn" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
Range("k" & x & ":bn" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
End If
Next x
Next i

End Sub
```

I tried to use `Cstr()` but nothing changed

UP: I've tried to use one more loop and cells instead of range and only thing I get is application-defined or object-defined error for this:

```
Dim z As Integer
...
For z = 6 To 30
If Cells(i, z).Value = Cells(x, z).Value And Cells(i, 5).Value <> Cells(x, 5).Value Then
```

tnx in advance

Comment: You can't compare entire range like this: `Range("K2:BN2").Value=Range("K3:BN3").Value`. See this question on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet/19396257#19396257

Comment: @simoco can I use cells().value instead?

Comment: you can compare only _one_ cell with _another_ cell. But you can't compare _entire ranges_ in that way. If you need compare entire ranges - see the link I gave you above

Comment: @simoco but when I use cells instead of range I get application-defined or object-defined error :(

Comment: how do you use them exactly?

Comment: @simoco I've updated topic, please take a look

Comment: it seems that your cells contains error in worksheet (like `#N/A`, `#DIV/0!`, `#VALUE!` and so on. Check please if it's true for you?

Comment: @simoco I've made dumb mistake with variable name, sorry, code is ok. But working not as needed, such a pity)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50030/discussion-between-simoco-and-seya)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare two ranges of the same "shape" but more than one cell.  Excel VBA does not allow this..something like:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:A2")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:B2")
    If r1.Value = r2.Value Then
        MsgBox "same"
    End If
End Sub
```

will fail.............you need an element-by-element comparison like:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:A2")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:B2")
    Dim i As Long, b As Boolean
    b = True
    For i = 1 To 2
        If r2(i).Value <> r1(i).Value Then
            b = False
        End If
    Next i
    If b Then
        MsgBox "same"
    End If
End Sub
```