# Compare cells in one row with another row in the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to all the wonderful members of this forum. I need some help please. I want to compare few cells in one row with another row in the same sheet. 
eg. I want to see if C1:G1 contains the same value as C2:G2

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks again

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two entire rows in a sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet)

Comment: @simoco he only wants certain cells though, not the whole row.

Comment: @tannman357, it doesn't matter, logic would be the same.. just change entire row to range

Comment: Oh...yeah that would work. I wrote some code that does his task anyways so I guess it doesn't matter....

Comment: Thank you for the replies, @tannman357 I have seen this and I tried range with my humble knowledge and it didn't work for me. Please be kind to convert the code for a range.

Answer (score 0):

In cell C3 insert the formula: `=IF(C1=C2, 1,0)` and extend it to cell G3. "1" indicated the match, "0" correspondingly, a mismatch. You can do it vice versa, like: `=IF(C1=C2,0,1)` and then apply SUM operator to cells: `SUM(C3:G3)`.  "0" indicates full match, any non-zero indicates number of cells with mismatches.

Or you can do it in VBA:

```
Function IsEqual() As Boolean

If Range("C1").Value & Range("D1").Value & Range("E1").Value & Range("F1").Value & Range("G1").Value = Range("C2").Value & Range("D2").Value & Range("E2").Value & Range("F2").Value & Range("G2").Value Then
    IsEqual = True
Else
    IsEqual = False
End If

End Function
```

Rgds,

Comment: Thank you for your response, I need to loop through the entire worksheet to find matching rows, so inserting formula into a cell is not ideal for this situation.

Comment: I've extended my answer pertinent to your requirement: see the modified post. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want!

```
Sub check()
Dim checkArr1, checkArr2 As Variant
Dim l As Long
Dim ElementsSame As Boolean

checkArr1 = Array(Range("C1"), Range("D1"), Range("E1"), Range("F1"), Range("G1"))
checkArr2 = Array(Range("C2"), Range("D2"), Range("E2"), Range("F2"), Range("G2"))

ElementsSame = True
For l = 0 To 4 'C to G is 5 (shifted left because array)
    If checkArr1(l) <> checkArr2(l) Then
        ElementsSame = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next l

If ElementsSame = True Then
    'do the stuff you want to do
    Range("A1") = 1 'I did this to error trap
Else
    Range("A1") = 0 'I did this to error trap
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this code. I need to loop through the whole sheet to how many rows are there with the same values in this range.