# Compare different ranges with bracket notation

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare range `A2` with `N2`, `A3` with `N3` , `A4` with `N4` and want the output in `L2` as `True/False` for the compared result of `A2` vs `N2` and the comparison result of `A3` with `N3` has to be in `L3` and like that.

Also the next comparison between `N2` with `N16` , `N3` with `N17`....

Please provide your feedback so that I can proceed further.

I have written the below code but selecting the range is not working for me:

```
Sub CompareCells()
    If [A2,A3] = [N2,N3] Then
        [L2,L3] = "yes"
    Else
        [L2,L3] = "no"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that sounds fairly simple.  Is there anything you need assistance with?

Comment: Yes I want the vba code to execute the above..

Comment: compare? What? =, >, <, >=, <=, <> ?

Comment: (a) There isn't enough info in the question to write VBA code for you (b) SO isn't a "code for me" site anyway.  We are willing to help you fix problems you have with **your** code, but you need to tell us what problems you are having.

Comment: I want to compare cell A2 with N2 , A3 with N3 , A4 with N4 like that upto row 30.

Comment: I am trying to write this code but this is not working.Sub CompareCells()
    If [A2,A3] = [N2,N3] Then
        [L2,L3] = "yes"
    Else
        [L2,L3] = "no"
    End If
End Sub     here I am not able to set the range for this array

Comment: (a) If that is your code, you should add it to the question.  (b) VBA doesn't handle array manipulations - use a loop - and post your new code if you have a problem.

Comment: can it be possible in this code to select the range of cells.?

Comment: Yes, VBA code can select the range of cells if that is what you need to do.  Update your question with your current code, and say what isn't working, and then we can assist you.

Comment: okok I will try with the Loop and come up if still faces any issue.

Comment: yes done the changes in the questions

Comment: You can compare ranges like `[A2:A30]` with `[N2:N30]`. If that is what you are after then try this `MsgBox Join(Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A30").Value), Chr(0)) = Join(Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("N2:N30").Value), Chr(0))` Credit where due... This beautiful piece of code was suggested by @TimWilliams [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet/19396257#19396257)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, VBA can't handle array manipulations such as `[A1,A2] = [N2,N3]` or `[L2,L3] = "yes"`, so you will either need to do each test individually, such as:

```
Sub CompareCells()
    If [A2] = [N2] Then [L2] = "yes" Else [L2] = "No"
    If [A3] = [N3] Then [L3] = "yes" Else [L3] = "No"
    If [A4] = [N4] Then [L4] = "yes" Else [L4] = "No"
End Sub
```

or you will need to have a loop, such as:

```
Sub CompareCells()
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 2 To 4
        If Cells(r, "A").Value = Cells(r, "N").Value Then
            Cells(r, "L").Value = "yes"
        Else
            Cells(r, "L").Value = "no"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

There isn't sufficient information in your question to know how to extend this code to compare N2 with N16, etc, but it should be easy enough for you to continue the above methods to handle it.

Comment: above query worked for me..:)                                                                          Sub CompareCells()
    If [A2] = [N2] Then [L2] = "yes" Else [L2] = "No"
    If [A3] = [N3] Then [L3] = "yes" Else [L3] = "No"
    If [A4] = [N4] Then [L4] = "yes" Else [L4] = "No"
End Sub

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...since t was weekend but still i got a wonderful response from you all..thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

When you use bracket notation e.g. `[A1]` you are using the [`EVALUATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223886(v=office.11).aspx) method:

> Using square brackets (for example, "[A1:C5]") is identical to calling the Evaluate method with a string argument.

You can use this to do what you want by setting the `Formula` property on a Range specified by bracket notation e.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareCells1()

    [L2:L10].Formula = "=IF(A2=N2,""yes"",""no"")"

End Sub
```

Note use of `:` to get a `Range` - using `,`s means you would do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareCells2()

    ' you need to type each cell reference upto L10....
    [L2, L3, L4, L5].Formula = "=IF(A2=N2,""yes"",""no"")"

End Sub
```

Which isn't as good as `CompareCells1`.

You can assign the range to a `Variant` but you can't simply compare two arrays like that - this won't work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareCells3()

    Dim var1, var2

    var1 = [A2:A10]
    var2 = [N2:N10]

    ' throws a Type Mismatch error
    If var1 = var2 Then
        ' this will never happen
    End If

End Sub
```

You can compare `var1` and `var2` per the faulty example above by using the `Transpose` and `Join` method [suggested by Siddarth in his comment, per Tim Williams post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet/19396257#19396257) but I think `CompareCells1` method is the easiest for you if you need, or want, to use bracket notation.

Using `,`s to do comparison will result in a false positive. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareCells4()

    Dim var1, var2

    var1 = [A2,A10]
    var2 = [N2,N10]

    ' creates a string from the range values
    If var1 = var2 Then
        ' this is a false positive - check the value of var1 and var2
        [L2:L10] = "False positive"
    End If

End Sub
```

Here `var1` is just the value of `A2` and `var2` is just the value of `N2` meaning even though you can set the range `L2:L10` with bracket notation doesn't get you the correct comparison per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for putting an answer. On weekends I am super lazy :D

Comment: No worries-  I was half-way through re-inventing the wheel for your pointer to Tim's answer when I saw your useful comment :)