# Simplify this into one sentence only

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, simplify

How can I simplify this into one sentence in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)?

```
 If [BT12] = "a" Then
   Range("AB12").ClearContents
 End If

 If [BT13] = "a" Then
   Range("AB13").ClearContents
 End If

 If [BT14] = "a" Then
   Range("AB14").ClearContents
 End If
```

Comment: In one sentence? You can't.

Comment: you could take this code to a Sub and have your _main_ code with a single line calling the Sub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is in one line:

```
[AB12:AB14] = [IF(BT12:BT14 = "a","",AB12:AB14)]
```

---

Here is another using UNION:

```
Union(IIf([BT12] = "a", [AB12], [AFD1040000]), IIf([BT13] = "a", [AB13], [AFD1040000]), IIf([BT14] = "a", [AB14], [AFD1040000])).ClearContents
```

The first creates an array of the values, either `""` or the value in the cell.  It is very concise and can easily be expanded to include a larger range.  The drawback is that if the data in AB is filled by formula the formula will be replaced by the value and the formula will be removed.

The second only clears those that need to be cleared leaving the others unchanged but is not as easily editable with larger ranges.

Comment: this third version of an one liner is brilliant +1)

Comment: Fine solutions, indeed

Answer (score 2):

here's your one-sentence code:

```
If Not [BT12:BT14].Find("a", , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Range(IIf([BT12] = "a", IIf([BT13] = "a", IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB12:AB14", "AB12:AB13"), IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB12,AB14", "AB12")), IIf([BT13] = "a", IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB13:AB14", "AB13"), IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB14", "")))).ClearContents
```

that you can (possibly) read more comfortably as:

```
    If Not [BT12:BT14].Find("a", , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Range( _
           IIf([BT12] = "a", _
                             IIf([BT13] = "a", _
                                               IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB12:AB14", "AB12:AB13"), _
                                               IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB12,AB14", "AB12") _
                                 ), _
                             IIf([BT13] = "a", _
                                               IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB13:AB14", "AB13"), _
                                               IIf([BT14] = "a", "AB14", "") _
                                 ) _
              ) _
          ).ClearContents
```

Comment: Don't bother much because I'm almost sure the OP will turn out to be asking for something completely different (my guess he has many `BTXX`s and `ABXX`s and he doesn't want to repeat the code for all of them). Some users just ask an _unclear_ question and don't even bother to be there to respond. Don't put so much effort into that :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, it's been just a funny exercise

Comment: That's awesome.

Comment: @DisplayName, nice alternative +1; see my approach using the `Application.Index` function.

Comment: Using union on can simplify the IIF's.  See below.  But the logic is sound here.

Answer (score 2):

This is bad practice and not recommended but is a one-liner. It is expected that this would be wrapped in a With statement holding the parent sheet reference.

```
Dim  i As Long: For i = 12 To 14: If .Cells(i, 72).Value = Chr$(97) Then .Cells(i, 28).ClearContents: Next
```

Comment: We don't know if OP is getting variable values from cells or not.  As I understood it, `[BTXX]' is just a variable right?

Comment: @ParrishHusband   No. It is shorthand notation for range reference. It uses the Evaluate method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601486/compare-different-ranges-with-bracket-notation

Comment: Interesting, have a link for that I can read?  I feel like I'm one of XKCD's 10,000 today.

Comment: And the official blurb https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-cells-by-using-shortcut-notation

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a one sentence code line. Whatever this should be useful for...

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it can be done :-)**

Just for fun: assuming you provide an ► empty cell in `[AB11]`, you can use this one liner via the `Application.Index` function:

```
[AB11:AB14] = Application.Transpose(Application.Index([AB11:AB14], Array(1, IIf([BT12] = "a", 1, 2), IIf([BT13] = "a", 1, 3), IIf([BT14] = "a", 1, 4)), 1))
```

(Edit thx DisplayName:)

**Amplifying remarks to the `Index` function**

You can find amplifying remarks to the use of the `Index` function at [Insert first column in array without Loops or API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Comment: I can't see how to reach the same functionality OP required. Did you test it?

Comment: @DisplayName - thank you, corrected answer, as I confused the columns.

Comment: No need to use the `application`.  Just use `Evaluate()` then you can use IF in an array.  See my answer.  But this gets closer to what the OP wanted as a true single line.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are asking for; the `IIF` function works, whether you are evaluating using a `True` or `False` clause. Try this one liner.

```
For Each cel In Range("BT12:BT14"): IIf cel = "a", cel.Offset(, -44).ClearContents, True: Next
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I simplify this into one sentence in vba?

Should you?  Your example code is concise, and easy to read.  As [Rawrplus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5512705/rawrplus) points out, shorter for the sake of being shorter is usually not a good idea.

One could simplify each line to this:

```
If [BT12] = "a" Then Range("AB12").ClearContents
If [BT13] = "a" Then Range("AB13").ClearContents
If [BT14] = "a" Then Range("AB14").ClearContents
```

Is that better?  Arguably no in my opinion.  If the actions of the condition ever need more complexity, you'll be forced to refactor anyway.

Comment: _"Is that better? Arguably no in my opinion."_. Well I do think that your code is better then the OP's one

Answer (score -1):

The quick answer is: it cant' be done. But one could figure out a solution if one want's to although it be rather far fetched.

First create a sub to put in a library module.

```
Sub ClearCellContent(ParamArray Args())
  Dim i As Integer, J As Integer
  i = UBound(Args)
  For J = 0 To i Step 3
    If Args(J).value = Args(J + 1) Then Args(J + 2).ClearContents
  Next
End Sub
```

From a somewhere in your code you can now call this sub like so:

```
ClearCellContent [BT12], "a", [AB12], [BT13], "a", [AB13], [BT14], "a", [AB14]
```

Like I said, far fetched but a oneliner of sorts.

Comment: _”The quick answer is: it cant' be done”_: well, that’s not true as you can see in my answer