# Excel vba loop through 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare values from two columns at once and I created wrote this code: It not works, first of all the second for loop (x1) uses different cells, but my intention was to use a break to get out from the for -loop after each step. I tried with Exit For but is not working. Any idea how I could compare 2 cells from 2 columns at once (with 2 for loops or not)? Thanks!

```
For x2 = x2Row To 2 Step -1
    For xl = xRow To 2 Step -1
          If ((Cells(xl, xCol) = Cells(xl - 1, xCol)) And (Cells(x2, x2Col) = Cells(x2 - 1, x2Col))) Then

        Cells(xl, xCol) = ""

    End If

    Next xl
Next x2
```

Comment: `I want to compare values from two columns at once` Have you seen @TimWilliams answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet)

Comment: Actually is not the same because my for goes "To 2 Step -1".. because I always need to compare 2 cells from a column and only then I switch to the second column

Comment: I tried something like this with exist for but is not working 
    For x2 = x2Row To 2 Step -1
        For xl = xRow To 2 Step -1
              If ((Cells(xl, xCol) = Cells(xl - 1, xCol)) And (Cells(x2, x2Col) = Cells(x2 - 1, x2Col))) Then
           
            Cells(xl, xCol) = ""
          
     
          
        End If
            
        Next xl
        Exit For
    Next x2

Comment: Have you got an example data set you’re working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this: Loop over all rows and check if there is a vertical pair. If yes, then check if its direct neighbor is also a vertical pair?

Then please try this

```
For x1 = xRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(x1, xCol) = Cells(x1 - 1, xCol) Then
        If Cells(x1, x2Col) = Cells(x1 - 1, x2Col) Then
            Cells(x1, xCol) = ""
        End If
    End If
Next x1
```

(Edit: xl vs. x1)