# Excel/VBA update file using another file

Tags: excel, vba

First, I'm sorry for my english but I need help:
I have a file where a macro add some lines, I have another file which is a copy of the first one, but when lines are added to the first one, i want these new lines on the second file when i open the workbook. So i think i have to use Workbook_open and compare both file to copy new lines to the 2nd file but i really don't have any idea how to do it, can someone help me ? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Can you please share your piece of script, so that we can know your approach.

Comment: I would use the Data, Get Data, From Workbook feature for this, not VBA.

Comment: @connecttopawan i didn't code the workbook_open yet, i don't know how to do

Comment: @jkpieterse i don't know that

Comment: Is this a 1 time deal or something it'd have to do daily?  [this may come in handy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395633/how-to-compare-two-entire-rows-in-a-sheet)

Comment: @JimmySmith everytime i open the second workbook

Comment: @MaximeFerreira  can you post that "macro" as it is?  It gives us somewhere to start helping you along

Comment: @JimmySmith the macros who add lines bro it so much macros there is a lot of files and hundreds of macros, it's for a  private company i can't give the file :/ but i just want to compare lines between both and add lines so the second one

Comment: I understand you can't give it all, but the small piece of existing macro where you want this code to go?  My link should give you a place to start.  Also, check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask