# Dynamically extend the upper limit of rows while open a file

Tags: excel, vba, macros, rows

I had to open a *".all"*  type file using VBA.
The problem is that this types of files have between 7.000.000 and 20.000.000 rows.

Im using this code:

```
Sub open()
book1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
file1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("ALL Files (*.all), *.all")
Worksheets("res").Range("K1").Value = file1
Workbooks.OpenText file1, origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlTextFormat
del = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveSheet.Copy before:=Workbooks(book1).Sheets(1)
Workbooks(del).Close False
Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "acti"
End Sub
```

With this routine I get a máximum number of 1.048.576 rows.

Any way to dynamically extend the upper limit of rows?

Thank you.

Comment: The extents of an Excel sheet is 1.048.576 rows  you will need to split your data accordingly onto multiple sheets.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f

Comment: It is any comand to split the data when uper limit is reached, after use Application.GetOpenFilename?

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to manipulate that amount of records in excel,  try to using arrays [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259595/load-csv-file-into-a-vba-array-rather-than-excel-sheet)