# Excel Vba "File already open" when its not - windows office

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read data from another spreadsheet in the same folder as my currently opened workbook, whenever I run this code I get the error file already open. Is there something wrong with my syntax or anything that might stop this from happening?

Here is the code.

```
Sub ReadFile()
    Infile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\smallDataset.csv"
    Open Infile For Input As #1
        Input #1, a, b
        Close #1
        Debug.Print (a & " " & b)
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the name of your *currently opened workbook*? (And nit-picking: A .csv file is  not a spreadsheet; it's a text file of comma-separated values (AKA a *CSV file*).)

Comment: Reboot your computer and try again.  Also, add a line `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path` to make sure it's returning the proper path.  (For example, it will be _blank_ if your workbook hasn't been saved.)  At first glance I think your syntax is a little off too, see [this detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259729/8112776) of reading csv with VBA.

Comment: If it's an error 55, it probably means that you already have a file open with a file handle of `#1`.  (Not necessarily the **same** file, just any file.)  Try entering `Close` (to close all open files) in the Immediate Window, and then run your code again

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to make sure there is no file open with handle #1

```
Sub ReadFile()
    InFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\smallDataset.csv"
    Close #1
    Open InFile For Input As #1
        Input #1, a, b
        Close #1
        Debug.Print (a & " " & b)
End Sub
```

Or you use Freefile to get the next number

```
Sub ReadFile
FileNumber = FreeFile

InFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\smallDataset.csv"

    Open InFile For Input As FileNumber
        Input #FileNumber, a, b
        Close #FileNumber
        Debug.Print (a & " " & b)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the errors which you have, these are the probable causes of the said error.

1) The `CSV` is open along with the `Excel` file
2) Your code has [memory leaks](http://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsd.htm)

To resolve number 1

- Try running the VBA code when the CSV is not opened

To resolve number 2

- Try to use close the `CSV`object after you have written your data inside it.

I'm not sure about your full code, but please check if you have something like `Excel.Close` or `Excel.Quit`.