# XML unexpected characters

Tags: xml, excel, vba, text-editor

I have a XML file that I'm creating with an Excel macro by concatenating strings.

The concatenation with the code is like:

```
xmlText = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" + vbCrLf
```

And the final creation of the file is with the code like:

```
Dim fso As Object
strPath = "C:\"
Set fso = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fso.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fso.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.    
fso.Open
' Write to file
fso.WriteText xmlText
fso.SaveToFile strPath, 2    
Set fso = Nothing
```

The problem I'm facing is that somehow there are unwanted characters that get inserted, but I can not see them in a normal editor, only when I check with a HEX editor.

With a normal editor I see the following:

[image]

With the HEX editor I see the following:

[image]

As you can see in the image there are the characters 'ï»¿' that I can not see with the normal editor.

How can I get rid of this unexpected characters?

I tried to change it to UTF16 as per suggestion in the comment by changing the following code:

```
fso.Charset = "utf-16"
```

and

```
xmlText = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-16""?>" + vbCrLf
```

The result in the HEX editor is like:

[image]

There seems to be still strange characters before

Comment: Are you using any special characters in XML data?

Comment: Yes, I have the following city name I need in the XML text: Dobříš

Comment: Hmm... not sure but if your same code works without that name then the name is the issue. Simple solution is to move to utf-16. Adds extra storage for symbol.

Comment: utf-16 seems to make it worse. I've edited the question above to show the outcome.

Comment: I've tried to replace the special characters in the body of the XML from Dobříš to Dobris, and it didn't make any difference. The strange characters in the HEX editor still appear

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it sorted with the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317605/escaping-non-ascii-characters-or-how-to-remove-the-bom) page from alj.

I initially thought that the problem was being resolved like:

```
xmlText = ""
xmlText = xmlText & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" + vbCrLf
```

When opening Notepad ++ in HEX I could see that the characters disappeared, but after closing and re-opening the file the characters re-appeared.

Anyway, removing BOM seems to be working for me now.